# when i click a button in my app, it makes app go to main fragment forcibly

Tags: java, android, xml

This app is already run normal, but when i click some button, i don't know why my app go to profile fragment (main fragment) can someone help me? my plan when the button clicked, it go to "`fragment_hasil_pengecekan`" fragment with result from form. for the details you can see this image :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5atI.jpg) i'm a newbie in here so please teach me how to resolve it.

Comment: `when i click a button in my app, it makes app go to main fragment forcibly` ite means your app is crashing

Comment: So how to resolve it?